# Spring kafka reset aggregation after restart application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use KafkaStreams aggregation with custom TimestampExtractor.
When I restart application my aggregation begins from beginning.

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder()
    KStream stream = builder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))

    KTable table = stream.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(aggregationMinutes)))
            .aggregate(
            { new AggregatorModel() },
            { key, value, aggregate ->


                return new aggregation.add(value)
            }
    )
            .toStream()
            .map({ k, v ->
        new KeyValue<>(k.window().end(), v)
    })
            .to('output')

    def config = new Properties()
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId)
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServerHost)
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 'group-id')
    config.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomTimestampExtractor.class.getName())
    config.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60))

    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config)
    kafkaStreams.start()
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: what is your `applicationId` value? is it the same from run to run?

Comment: Application id does not change from run to run.

Comment: Meta comment: you don't need to specify `group.id` -- the `application.id` is use as group ID. Why do you point out that your are using a custom `TimestampExtractor`? This should be independent from the timestamp extractor. Or do you claim, that the problem is resolved if you don't use a custom extractor? After you stopped the application, did you check if it committed it's offsets correctly (eg, using `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`)? Do you call `kafkaStreams#close()` on shutdown to make sure it commit on shutdown?

Comment: I've getting records (e.g. `{key: f5ter, value: {createDate: 1535724900000, name: 'name', needToCount: 4 ...}}`). In my timestamp extractor I return's `record.createDate`. After aggregation I've getting object with Windowed key  and myAggregatedValue. I need custom TimestampExtractor to aggregate my records from - to createDate of record. Before shutdown I call `kafkaStream.close()`

Comment: I mean if I have aggregation `12:00 - 12:15` and now 12:30 and I get record with createDate `12:13`, I want this record to be in aggregation `12:00 - 12:15`. But if I restart application, aggregation `12:00 - 12:15` starts from beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I aggregated data more than 3 days ago, but param "windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms" by default setting 24h. And my aggregation starts from begin. When I aggregate the data for the current day, everything goes fine.